# Custom placeholder in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qtwidgets

I want to have a `QLineEdit` with the specific placeholder text format: it needs to have left aligned and right aligned text. Here is an example:

[image: example]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this seems to be all hard coded](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/d0a6fcd925dc2a1553e2086e85f59ba76db85bef:src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp#L1872) in `void QLineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` as follows:

```
if (d->shouldShowPlaceholderText()) {
    if (!d->placeholderText.isEmpty()) {
        QColor col = pal.text().color();
        col.setAlpha(128);
        QPen oldpen = p.pen();
        p.setPen(col);
        QRect ph = lineRect.adjusted(minLB, 0, 0, 0);
        QString elidedText = fm.elidedText(d->placeholderText, Qt::ElideRight, ph.width());
        p.drawText(ph, va, elidedText);
        p.setPen(oldpen);
    }    
}
```

You could reimplement this on your own in a subclass if you wish.

Naturally, you could also "cheat" with space and font sizes, but that would require a bit more work, and would be nastier in the end, too, let alone long-term reliability.

You could also contribute to the Qt Project to make this class more flexible, but they could reject it with the reason of not being common case enough. It is up to the maintainer(s).

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I've created the code from these sources.

Comment: @Deutsche: please select an answer then. By the way, why are you calling the baseclass' method?

Comment: because first of all the QLineEdit needs to be painted (background, border) and then this custom placeholder is painted over the picture of QLineEdit.

Comment: @Deutsche: cannot you do that all in your paintEvent without the baseclass'?

Comment: No, because I don't want to do it :) The painting code is already created by the Qt team, and I just add a small portion of my painting for it. If some part of this code (Qt code) is changed in the future, I won't need to maintain it in my code.

Comment: @Deutsche: ok fair enough, if the rendering performance difference is negligible, I agree with you, and it probably is.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @lpapp ! His advice is right. Here is the code, I created from [the Qt sources](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/d0a6fcd925dc2a1553e2086e85f59ba76db85bef:src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp#L1886-1906) suggested by @lpapp :

```
void LineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QLineEdit::paintEvent(e);
    if (!text().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    QPainter p(this);

    QStyleOptionFrameV2 panel;
    initStyleOption(&panel);
    QRect r = style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_LineEditContents, &panel, this);
    r.setX(r.x() + textMargins().left());
    r.setY(r.y() + textMargins().top());
    r.setRight(r.right() - textMargins().right());
    r.setBottom(r.bottom() - textMargins().bottom());

    QFontMetrics fm = fontMetrics();
    int minLB = qMax(0, -fm.minLeftBearing());
    int minRB = qMax(0, -fm.minRightBearing());
    int vscroll = r.y() + (r.height() - fm.height() + 1) / 2;
    static const int horizontalMargin = 2; // QLineEditPrivate::horizontalMargin
    QRect lineRect(r.x() + horizontalMargin, vscroll, r.width() - 2*horizontalMargin, fm.height());
    QRect ph = lineRect.adjusted(minLB, 0, -minRB, 0);

    QColor col = palette().text().color();
    col.setAlpha(128);
    p.setPen(col);

    QString left = fm.elidedText("left", Qt::ElideRight, ph.width());
    Qt::Alignment leftAlignment = QStyle::visualAlignment(Qt::LeftToRight, QFlag(Qt::AlignLeft));
    p.drawText(ph, leftAlignment, left);

    QString right = fm.elidedText("right", Qt::ElideRight, ph.width());
    Qt::Alignment rightAlignment = QStyle::visualAlignment(Qt::LeftToRight, QFlag(Qt::AlignRight));
    p.drawText(ph, rightAlignment, right);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an easy way to do this. You could try to calculate the pixel width (using QFontMetrics) of both placeholder-parts and calculate the number of spaces you need to insert between the placeholder-parts to let them appear aligned. You wuld need to set/update the calculated placeholder whenever the size of the widget changes.